# Definition of interior points is confusing

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let X be a Banach space. Let C be a convex set in X. Then,

(1) A point $p\in C$ is an interior point if and only if for every $y\in X$, we have there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $t\in[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, we have $p+ty\in C$

is this the same as the normal way of thinking about an interior point?

i.e. (2) there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $B_{||\,\cdotp\,||}(p,\delta)\subseteq C$.

And is the convexity of C required to make them the same definition if so? And how do we choose a $\delta$ if we want to show (1) imples (2)?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I quite get your meaning. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2|x|}$, then $0+tx\in C$ for every $t\in[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Thus, as $x$ was arbitrary, $0$ is an interior point by definition (1).

Comment: What may happen is that it is the starting point of a particular study in relation to convexity and the author is recalling the definition of an open set i.e. That he is interested in open convexs.A plane figure (although you should not rely too much on geometric intuition for many problems) could help you see clearly that the two definitions are equivalent. And better if you complement it with a closed figure.

Comment: You are correct. I've deleted my comments so they don't confuse anyone.